# 「命令形 + と助詞」どんな意味？

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics

アナと雪の女王2の「Into the Unknown・心のままに」の歌詞を翻訳していますが、次の文型が分かりません。分からない部分は この の間に...

1) 聞こえてる、でも無駄よ。目を覚ませ、起きろと

2) 未知の旅へ踏み出せと

「起きる」と「踏み出す」の意味は分かりますが、この「起きろ+と / 踏み出せ+と」という文型のニュアンスが理解できません。

皆さん、教えてください。
よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

どちらも「引用{いんよう}の『と』」 ("quotative と") になります。

実際{じっさい}の歌詞{かし}を見てみましょう。

> １）聞{き}こえてる　でも無駄{むだ}よ
>
> 目を覚{さ}ませ　起{お}きろ**と**
>
> どこかで呼{よ}ぶ　謎{なぞ}めいた声{こえ}

この部分{ぶぶん}は、一般的{いっぱんてき}な散文{さんぶん}では次{つぎ}のようになります。

> 聞こえてる、でも無駄よ。
>
> 「目を覚ませ！」、「起きろ！」**と**
>
> 謎めいた声がどこかで呼んでいる。

「～～**と**呼んでいる」という文型{ぶんけい}です。主語{しゅご}は「謎めいた声」です。

要{よう}するに、どこかで誰かが「目を覚ませ！」、「起きろ！」**と**言っているという意味{いみ}になります。まさに引用そのものです。

> ２）それでも　あの声は　求{もと}めている
>
> 未知{みち}の旅{たび}へ　踏{ふ}み出{だ}せ**と**

これを散文に直{なお}すと以下{いか}のようになります。

> それでもあの声は、「未知の旅へ踏み出せ！」**と**求めている。

「～～**と**求めている」という文型です。主語は「あの声」です。

その声が話者{わしゃ}に対{たい}して「未知の旅へ踏み出せ！」と要求{ようきゅう}しているのです。こちらも日本語では引用とみなされます。